# "Wrong" app gets pinned to taskbar (Windows 7)

Tags: java, windows-7, taskbar, shortcut, createprocess

I have an application that gets started via a shortcut. This application than starts a Java GUI application with CreateProcess().

When the Java application gets pinned to the taskbar the javaw.exe gets pinned to the taskbar instead of the "expected" shortcut. Only the native executable which launches Java can be modified - the shortcut has to stay.

What has to be done so that the shortcut gets pinned?

Comment: Have you gotten any further in resolving this issue? I am facing precisely the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately: No - I wish I had
If I find a solution I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like winrun4j or create a .bat instead of using a shortcut.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no option.

Comment: @kts: I can't get WinRun4J to work under Eclipse Galileo. The plugin website is rather uninformative, and I can't figure out if it's my version of Eclipse or if I'm doing something wrong. I installed it via "Help", "Install New Software...", then specifying the Update Site. After restarting, it appears in my installed software list, but WinRun4J doesn't appear under the Run Configurations list. Any ideas?

Comment: @Paul I never had eclipse integration with winrun4j. I just downloaded the zip which contains an executable and ini and an icon. Rename the executable to what you want, rename the ini and edit, create a ico with the same name (eg foo.exe, foo.ini, foo.ico) and run (IIRC) foo.exe -WinRun4j::SetIcon to change the exe icon.

Comment: @kts: Thanks, that clarifies things. I was hopeful it would integrate better than Launch4j, but I'm not sure if this is a fundamental improvement. I read there is a way of embedding the INI into the executable. Is this true?

Comment: @Paul: I don't know of an easy way to do it. Grab the source code and change the function that reads the ini file to return a hard-coded arguments list instead of reading it from the file. I guess you could modify the program to read the ini options out of the META-INI direcory (or some such) instead of a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You could clean your `IconCache` like this:

First go to Task Manager and kill `explorer.exe`

`Windows Task Management -> Processes -> End "explorer.exe"`

Then, in the Task Management

`Windows Task Management -> File -> New -> CMD.EXE`

In the opened console type:

`CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local DEL IconCache.db /a EXIT`

Then reopen the `explorer.exe`

`Windows Task Management -> File -> New -> explorer.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You can pin a shortcut directly, not necessarily a window that is open on taskbar: right click on the shortcut, Pin to taskbar. The java window that will open won't use the button you pinned on the taskbar, since it's a different application, but that was not the issue, I understand.